# How to create *.aar file from "existing" android studio project ( Not creating new android library)?

Tags: android, aar

I searched how to create *.aar file but all of them say to create library then add your classes then Double click assemble ... the *.aar is created in build/...

but I need to create *.aar file from existing (already created and coded) project

so my question is :

how to create *.aar file from "existing" android studio project ( Not creating new android library) ?

Thanks in advance

---

I did Morrison Chang's solution (thx)

[image: the solution to convert project to library]

made it as module library 
after double clicking on assemble some errors come :
[image: you can see errors here]

Comment: You didn't find this: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#Convert

Comment: thx Morrison check the question again plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did what morrison said I got that error which i sent as photo 
the solution for that error was just to "Rebuilt project" after "File/Sync project ..." 
( which is funny :) )

now I have aar file in my app/build/...

[image: result as *.aar]